"Ein Tag im Jahre ist den Toten frei" (H. von Gilm. Allerseelen)

Es blüht und funkelt heut auf jedem Grabe,
Ein Tag im Jahre ist den Toten frei;
Komm’ an mein Herz, daß ich dich wieder habe,
Wie einst im Mai.
Verse 3 from the poem "Allerseelen" (1840)
by Hermann von Gilm zu Rosenegg (1812–1864)
full text

The only meaning my limited Deutsch permits me to see is:
Ein Tag im Jahre sind die Toten frei. I cannot see, why the poet wrote ist den Toten frei.

See lieder.net for the full text and an English translation.

@guidot - For what it's worth, there are several performances of the Strauss setting on YouTube, for exampe here. There is a Wikipedia article for the Strauss version as well, and this also has an English translation.

German has four grammatical cases, and which one to use usually depends on either the main verb of the sentence (if its an object) or a preposition (if its part of a prepositional phrase).
There are two other rules that you probably already know:

The subject is always in the nominative case.
Possessive attributes in a nominal phrase are in the genitive case.

Here is an example:

Die Hinterbliebenen gedachten trotz des schlechten Wetters der Gefallenen des schrecklichen Krieges.
Despite the bad weather, the bereaved commemorated the fallen of the terrible war.


Die Hinterbliebenen
Subject, therefore nominative case
des schlechten Wetters
Part of the prepositional phrase "trotz des schlechten Wetters". The preposition "trotz" needs genitive case, and therefore "des schlechten Wetters" is in genitive case. (Dependence from preposition)
der Gefallenen
This is the verb's object. The verb "gedenken" needs its object to be in genitive case, so "der Gefallenen" is in genitive case. (Dependence from verb)
des schrecklichen Krieges
Possessive attribute of "der Gefallenen" and therefore in genitive case. (Possessive attribute of another noun)

So these rules describe parts of speech that are dependent on other parts.
But German also has parts of speech that are free and independent. And one of the most important parts of this class is called:
Free dative
A free dative is a part of speech that can be removed from a sentence without changing anything else, so that the remaining sentence is still a valid sentence (probably with a slightly different meaning).


Ein Tag im Jahre ist frei.
Ein Tag im Jahre ist den Toten frei.


Sentence 1: One day a year is free.
Sentence 2: One day a year is free to the dead.
A free day means a vacation, so you don't have to do what you usually do. You are free to decide what you want to do. It does not mean that you are a prisoner on the other days. And so this sentence does not mean that the dead are held prisoner for the rest of the year. It means that the dead do their usual dead stuff (whatever that may be) for the rest of the year, but there is one day a year when they can decide for themselves what to do. That day is their holiday.
In sentence 2 we have a beneficiary in the dative case, which is not present in sentence 1. This dative is not dependent on a verb or a preposition or any other grammatical things in its environment. This dative is therefore free and is called the "free dative" (in German: freier Dativ).
There are even more uses for free datives:

Dativus commodi

Der Wunsch ging ihr in Erfüllung.


Dativus incommodi

Dem Kellner ist eines der Gläser kaputt gegangen.


Dativus ethicus

Bitte fall mir ja nicht von da oben runter!


Dativus judicantis

Das ging mir zu schnell.




I think of this as POV dative, meaning that the dative expresses an experience or opinion from a particular point of view, not an absolute fact. In many cases it can be translated into English with "to" or "for". So the last example becomes: "That was too fast for me."

@RDBury yes that's what I understand by "dativus judicantis". The dative mir expresses whose "judgement" or opinion or POV the sentence is.

If you say "[...] sind die Toten Frei" it translates to "[...] are the dead free".
But "[...] ist den Toten frei" means "[...] is free for the dead".
As far as I understand Germanic old gods, there was one who was the lord of the dead. And he gave one free day to the dead every year for them to visit the world of the living.
The meaning of "frei" you used is freedom of an individual. But the text uses "frei" in the sense of vacation or a day without responsibilities.
There is also a difference in grammar:
Ich gebe jemanden frei. I set somebody free.
Ich gebe jemandem frei. I give somebody free time.

I haven't ever heard about a relation to old Germanic gods, but is was a common superstition in catholic regions that the souls of the dead come back for one day on Allerseelen (All Souls, November 2) to visit their family or descendants. See e.g. https://www.allgaeuer-zeitung.de/allgaeu/allerseelen-heute-in-bayern-feiertag-braeuche-aberglaube-und-unterschied-zu-allerheiligen_arid-337645

The title of the poem is "Allerseelen" (All Souls' Day). Quote from Wikipedia:

All Souls' Day, also called The Commemoration of All the Faithful Departed, is a day of prayer and remembrance for the faithful departed, observed by Christians on 2 November. Through prayer, intercessions, alms and visits to cemeteries, people commemorate the poor souls in purgatory and gain them indulgences.

On All Souls' Day it is (or was) common in Christian countries  to visit the graves of beloved people. This is what the poet does: He visits the grave of a lost love and melancholically remembers the deceased person. The refrain line "Wie einst im Mai" (like once in May)  is an incantation of a happy past.
The phrase "Ein Tag im Jahre ist den Toten frei" has been grammatically explained by Hubert Schölnast. But what does it mean? It means that All Souls' Day is reserved for the dead, is dedicated exclusively to them: It is kept free for commemoration.
